# Merging two dataframes with multiples in one of them

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am merging two dataframes under the common header, "COUNTERPARTYNAME". So below is an example of my df5:

```
    CONTRACT                COUNTERPARTYNAME           TERM
0     450                          A                      300

1     400                          A                      350

2     270                          B                      600

3     360                          C                      300
...
```

And df6:

```
    COUNTERPARTYNAME          CBA               DAN
0           A                     500               10

1           B                     300               3

2           C                     400               9

3           D                     650               10

...
```

But essentially both dataframes share the COUNTERPARTYNAME, but there are multiples of certain cpty's in df5. I'm trying to merge the two, such that they are merged in a new df, and for every cpty, the CBA and DAN will show up next to it, including for the multiples.

My expected result would be like so:

```
 CONTRACT               COUNTERPARTYNAME           TERM        CBA     DAN
0     450                          A               300         500     10

1     400                          A               350         500     10

2     270                          B               600         300     3

3     360                          C               300         400     9
...
```

I understand how to merge it for one on one's, like if there was only one A, B, C, etc... in df5, just like there in df6.

However, when I've tried:

```
df7=pd.merge(df5, df6),
```

hoping they would merge on the COUNTERPARTYNAME, and then print it, a lot of my data on certain cpty's disappears, while other cpty's pop up more than they actually showed up in df5. For example, I have 2 A's and 2 B's in df5, but when I merge, I for some reason now have 0 A's and like 6 B's. The CBA and DAN are right, and corresponding, but I feel like I've lost some of my data for some reason. Is there a way to right this? Am I doing the wrong type of merge?

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: Yes, please look at the edited, what I would expect, or hope the result to be, is now included

Comment: Dude, knock it off and at least *TRY* to do your job.

Comment: Seriously, look at your help history, throway172.  Every time you run into a problem with one specific query, you come here and post a question about it.  I saw several posts in your history about the same exact query - each about an incremental change/fix you needed to make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly say on which column, you want your merge to be. Also you have to use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as below.

```
df7 = df5.merge(df6, on=['COUNTERPARTYNAME'])
```

Output:

```
  CONTRACT COUNTERPARTYNAME TERM  CBA DAN
0      450                A  300  500  10
1      400                A  350  500  10
2      270                B  600  300   3
3      360                C  300  400   9
```

Comment: Yeah, for some reason that's still giving me the same output. Huh, I don't know why that is.

Comment: What output is that? @throway172

Comment: I'm getting all the relevant columns, so the merge is working, but all my A counterparties are gone, as well as some others. It basicaly seems like the merge worked, but some of my data from df5 was lost in the transaction. Like "A" pops up under COUNTERPARTYNAME in both df's i'm merging, yet in the actual merge "A" is gone

Comment: That is strange. Are you sure there are no trailing or leading white spaces in `COUNTERPARTYNAME` ? Try `df5.COUNTERPARTYNAME = df5.COUNTERPARTYNAME.apply(lambda x: x.strip())` before merging. May be the strip it for df6 as well?

Comment: I did the strip for both of them, and got the error 'float object has no attribute' 'strip'

Comment: try ...`.apply(lambda x: str(x).strip())`.

Comment: same result. I guess there's something fundamentally wrong with the dataframe that i got from SQL potentially? I just don't get why it woun't merge correctly

Comment: It seems to be the case.